# How to keep added classes after page reloads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu that is sliding from the right side on click (this is codded in WordPress theme).
Due to transform and translate having blur problems I developed some of mine css and custom jQueries to do animations on my way.
However, I have a problem that when page reloads **my added classes won't stay added**.

So I guess I have to keep jQuery as it is once page reloads.
localStorage function probably or something similar, but I am not familiar with this.

This is jQuery I have:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".sidemenu-trigger").on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$(".sidemenu-trigger").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".sidemenu-trigger").addClass("active").css({
        x: "x",
      });
    } else {
      $(".sidemenu-trigger").removeClass("active").css({
        x: "x",
      });
    }
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".sidemenu-trigger").on("click", function (e) {
    if ($(".sidemenu-trigger").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".grid-parent").addClass("collapsed-menu").css({
        x: "x",
      });
    } else {
      $(".grid-parent").removeClass("collapsed-menu").css({
        x: "x",
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If I reload page on active status, side menu keeps being collapsed, but there is no active class on .sidemenu-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save to localStorage: `localStorage.setItem('sidebar', sidebarActive);`

Read localStorage: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sidebar'))`

Don't forget to update localStorage while `sidebarActive` changed.

```js
const sidebar = $(".sidemenu-trigger");
let sidebarActive = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sidebar")) || false;
sidebar.toggleClass("active", sidebarActive);

sidebar.on("click", () => {
  sidebarActive = !sidebarActive;
  sidebar.toggleClass("active", sidebarActive);
  $(".grid-parent").toggleClass("collapsed-menu", sidebarActive);
  localStorage.setItem("sidebar", sidebarActive);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!
How would I use this same thing for .grid-parent (When sidebar active add and localstore active class on .grid-parent)?
Can you update question with that too as separate function from the one above.

Comment: Just noticed this also fires wherever is clicked on page.

Comment: Fixed the problem with $(document).on('click', ".sidemenu-trigger", () => {

Now, I am not sure how to make it work with .grid-parent still.

Comment: You can add it in same function if they are both triggered by `.sidemenu-trigger` click event. I edit my ans.